# How to copy a directory to another (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, copy

I have two directories:

```
/home/me/project1
/home/me/project1-mirror
```

Now i would like to copy:

```
/home/me/project1/lib/*
/home/me/project1-mirror/lib
/home/me/project1/test/*
/home/me/project1-mirror/test/*
```

How can i handle that? A good thing woule be, if /home/me works for other users too.

Comment: What is `project-mirror`? Is it a source or destination directory? Why doesn't `project2` appear in your second code listing? It would help if you edit your code listing so it would be clear what is a source and what is destination, like this: `/home/me/project1/lib/* -> /home/me/project2/lib/*`

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question right now. I meant to copy the content from project1 to project1-mirror. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.cp_r 'project1/lib/.', 'project1-mirror/lib', verbose: true
FileUtils.cp_r 'project1/test/.', 'project1-mirror/test', verbose: true
```

A quote from [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r)

```
# If you want to copy all contents of a directory instead of the
# directory itself, c.f. src/x -> dest/x, src/y -> dest/y,
# use following code.
FileUtils.cp_r 'src/.', 'dest'     # cp_r('src', 'dest') makes dest/src,
                                   # but this doesn't.
```